# Example of a convex set that exist in a space that does not carry a topology.

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I want an example of what is being said here (first answer) on quora:

https://www.quora.com/Topology-is-a-convex-set-always-compact-by-definition

``Similarly, convex sets may exist in spaces that don’t carry a topology (though this is less common.)´´

Is it just something trivial like ``just don´t put a topology in the thing´´ or is there a more cool example?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd go with take any vector space and just dont put a topology

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, is having a vectorial space structure necessary for talking on convexity or is there something algebraic that is less strong for me to be talking on convexity?

Comment: Well, you need to have the notion of "a line segment". Since the line segment with endpoints $x,y$ is usually parametrized as $\{tx+(1-t)y: t\in[0,1]\}$ you need i presume a vector space (for addition and scalar multiplication); I am not an expert but I haven't seen convexity on more general structures than vector spaces. Then again, I'm not very experienced.

Comment: Take any partial order, which don't have an agreed upon topology, and you can have convex sets lacking in both a topology nor need of any of that messy +×÷ arithmetical stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot, William and Just. Your comments are very useful to me. You may answer my question to get the points if you want. For me not being unfair, I would give them to the first anwerer of you two.

Comment: On every space you can define some topologies (e.g. the discrete and the chaotic topology). Hence, it is not quite clear what "don't carry a topology" means.